# How to write reg expression to replace the price value with specific format

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use a regular expression to represent values with the specific format.
For example, if a user writes "1" into the input box, then it has to be replaced "$1"

examples:

- 1234 -> $1,234
- 1234.5 -> $1,234.5
- 0.31 -> $0.31
- 3.01 -> $3.01

I tried it like this.

```
formatNumber = (n) => {
    console.log(n);
    return n.toString().replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

handleUserInput = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name
    const value = e.target.value
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
    let errors = this.state.errors;
    e.target.value = '$' + this.formatNumber(value);
}
```

It works with integer values, but not decimal values.
I really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: You are removing all the non digits including the dot. You could omit this part to keep the dots `.replace(/\D/g, "")`

Answer (score 0):

With the first replace `.replace(/\D/g, "")` you are removing the dots as well. If you want to keep the dots, you could use `[^\d.]+` instead of `\D`

For example

```js
formatNumber = (n) => {
  return n.toString()
    .replace(/[^\d.]+/g, "")
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
};

[
  1234,
  1234.5,
  0.31,
  3.01

].forEach(s => console.log(formatNumber(s)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You do something like this:

```js
const formatNumber = n => {
  const [a, ...rest] = n.toString()
  const m =
    rest.toString().length % 3 === 0 ?
    rest
    .toString()
    .replace(/\D/g, "")
    .replace(/\d{3}/g, n => `${n}.`) :
    rest.toString().replace(/\D/g, "")
  return `$${a},${m}`
}

console.log(formatNumber(1234.5))
console.log(formatNumber(1234))
console.log(formatNumber(0.31))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below function. I think it is helpful to you.

```
function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return '$'+ x1 + x2;
}
```